# mongodb relations

Tags: mongoid, mongodb

Please, can you say me, think i good or bad?

I have two objects, `Exhibition` and `Stand`. In my logic `Exhibition` has_many `Stands`.
I want to use mongodb. First, i can do Stand embedded in Exhibition. But several exhibitions can include same stand. After this i think, that will be better to create two documents(collections): `Exhibition` and `Stand` and imitate relation references.

```
     1.Is it good idea?
```

If it is good idea, than i create in Exhibition document field stand_ids, which will be array and i will push in this field necessary stand ids.

```
     2.When i push ids in Exhibition and after this i 
       want to delete reference stand in Stands document. 
       How will be better to destroy id in Exhibition.stand_ids.

     3.Think i by relational or it is good practice?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with relations you should use a relational DB. It doesn't make sense to use a noSQL solution if your data has structure.

My advice to you would be to use the tool most suited for the job. What you're trying to do seems to be ideal for a relational DB.

Comment: In my database will be dynamic fields, in relation db it will bad.

Comment: you could use the EAV pattern to handle meta keys : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model depends on your situ though

Answer (score 0):

```
class Exhibition
  embeds_many :stands
end

class Stand
  embedded_in :exhibition
end
```

use above relationship in each of the class.

Comment: relations isn't bad in documents databases?

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will be right for you http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design

**Use Cases**

*Customer / Order / Order Line-Item*

> Orders should be a collection. customers a collection. line-items should be an array of line-items embedded in the order object.

*Blogging system.*

> Posts should be a collection. post author might be a separate collection, or simply a field within posts if only an email address. comments should be embedded objects within a post for performance.

**Schema Design Basics**

*Kyle Banker, 10gen*

> http://www.10gen.com/presentation/mongosf2011/schemabasics

*Indexing & Query Optimization
Alvin Richards, Senior Director of Enterprise Engineering*

> http://www.10gen.com/presentation/mongosf-2011/mongodb-indexing-query-optimization

**These 2 videos are the bests on mongoddb ever seen imho*